# Use Alias In Join Condition

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I want to use `"MaxID"` as part of my join condition, but it keeps throwing an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
>   LINE 29:   AND t1.["MaxID"]=t2.id

This is my query:

```
with MaxIDs as
(
 select max(id) as "MaxID"
 ,elID
 from valsum
 group by elID
)
select 
t1.elID
,es.eNum
,es.des
,es.d1
,case 
  when es.st = 1 then 'Pink' 
  when es.st = 2 then 'Red' 
  when es.st = 3 then 'Blue' 
  ELSE es.st::text 
END AS st
,t1.price
from MaxIDs t1
INNER JOIN etime es 
ON t1.elID=es.elID
join valsum t2 
ON t1.elID=t2.elID 
AND t1.MaxID=t2.id   
WHERE CAST(es.d1 As Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
AND es.st IN (3) 
ORDER BY CAST(es.d1 As Date) DESC
```

I also tried to use the alias w/o the brackets, but the same error was thrown.  How can I join on this field?

With no brackets and no quotes this is the error:

```
AND t1.MaxID=t2.id
```

> ERROR:  column t1.maxid does not exist
>   LINE 29:   AND t1.MaxID=t2.id

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#sql-syntax-identifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `t1."MaxID"` literally the same as in `with` or drop quotes in `with`.